# Can a person Sprinkle Mei Niddah on many people?

Tags: tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

Please correct me if I get details wrong.

Someone who is tamei met has to have the water with the red heifer ashes in it sprinkled on him twice (days 1 and 7) by way of a hyssop branch. The sprinkler becomes impure by the action. Does that impurity stop him from sprinkling anyone else until he becomes pure again (which I assume is after a trip to the mikvah and a pause until the evening). Can he only sprinkle one person (or maybe a small group?) per day? Or can he keep sprinkling because he doesn't have to be pure in order to sprinkle others?

If I only have 65 kohanim who can sprinkle, does this put a local limit on the number of people who can be purified on a given day?

(inspired by page 163-164 of The Falconi Effect)

Comment: See Rambam Parah chapter 15. The Kohen doesn't become Tamei like you expect

Comment: So does the Rambam say that if one sprinkles l'tzorech, he doesn't become tamei at all? "אינו מדבר במזה על הטמא--אם טיהר את הטמא, קל וחומר שיהיה הוא טהור" This would mean he can keep sprinkling people who wait in line.

Answer (score 1):

See Mishna Para 12:4 where it states clearly that one person would sprinkle on large groups of people.

> הַמַּזֶּה מֵחַלּוֹן שֶׁל רַבִּים וְנִכְנַס לַמִּקְדָּשׁ וְנִמְצְאוּ הַמַּיִם פְּסוּלִים, פָּטוּר
>
> ר"ע מברטנורה  הַמַּזֶּה מֵחַלּוֹן שֶׁל רַבִּים. שֶׁעוֹמֵד בְּחַלּוֹן שֶׁל רַבִּים וְהִזָּה שָׁם עַל הַטְּמֵאִים הָעוֹבְרִים, וְהִזָּה עַל הַטָּמֵא כְּסָבוּר שֶׁהַמַּיִם שֶׁבְּיָדוֹ טְהוֹרִים לְהַזָּאָה‏

As DoubleAA already pointed out in a comment, the person who sprinkles the water on impure people to purify them does not become impure - if he makes others pure how can he become impure - as the Rambam codifies.

> הלכות פרה אדומה - פרק חמשה עשר
> א  הַנּוֹגֵעַ בְּמֵי חַטָּאת שֶׁלֹּא לְצֹרֶךְ הַזָּאָה בֵּין אָדָם בֵּין כֵּלִים טָמֵא וְאֵינוֹ מְטַמֵּא בְּגָדִים בִּשְׁעַת מַגָּעוֹ. שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (במדבר יט-כא) 'וְהַנֹּגֵעַ בְּמֵי הַנִּדָּה יִטְמָא עַד הָעָרֶב'. הִנֵּה לָמַדְתָּ שֶׁמֵּי הַנִּדָּה אָב מֵאֲבוֹת הַטֻּמְאוֹת שֶׁל תּוֹרָה. וְטֻמְאַת מַגָּעָן בְּכָל שֶׁהוּא. וְאִם הָיָה בָּהֶן כְּדֵי הַזָּאָה מְטַמְּאִין בְּמַגָּע וּבְמַשָּׂא. וְהַנּוֹגֵעַ בָּהֶן אוֹ שֶׁנּוֹשְׂאָן שֶׁלֹּא לְצֹרֶךְ מְטַמֵּא בְּגָדִים בִּשְׁעַת מַגָּעוֹ אוֹ בִּשְׁעַת מַשָּׂאוֹ עַד שֶׁיִּפְרשׁ מִמְּטַמְּאָיו שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (במדבר יט-כא) **'וּמַזֵּה מֵי הַנִּדָּה יְכַבֵּס בְּגָדָיו'. אֵינוֹ מְדַבֵּר בְּמַזֶּה עַל הַטָּמֵא אִם טִהֵר אֶת הַטָּמֵא קַל וָחֹמֶר שֶׁיִּהְיֶה הוּא טָהוֹר. מִפִּי הַשְּׁמוּעָה לָמְדוּ שֶׁזֶּה שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר בַּתּוֹרָה וּמַזֵּה מֵי הַנִּדָּה לֹא נֶאֱמַר אֶלָּא לְשִׁעוּר שֶׁהַנּוֹגֵעַ אוֹ הַנּוֹשֵׂא מֵי נִדָּה שֶׁיֵּשׁ בָּהֶן כְּדֵי הַזָּיָה שֶׁלֹּא לְצֹרֶךְ הַזָּאָה טָמֵא וּמְטַמֵּא בְּגָדִים דִּין תּוֹרָה.** וְכַמָּה הוּא שִׁעוּר הַזָּאָה כְּדֵי שֶׁיִּטְבּל רָאשֵׁי גִּבְעוֹלִין שֶׁל אֵזוֹב בְּמַיִם. בַּמֶּה דְּבָרִים אֲמוּרִים שֶׁמֵּי חַטָּאת מְטַמְּאִין בִּזְמַן שֶׁנָּגַע בָּהֶן אוֹ נְשָׂאָן שֶׁלֹּא לְצֹרֶךְ קֹדֶם שֶׁיַּעֲשׂוּ מִצְוָתָן. אֲבָל אַחַר שֶׁעָשׂוּ מִצְוָתָן אֵינָן מְטַמְּאִין כְּלָל. כֵּיצַד. הֲרֵי שֶׁטָּבַל אֶת הָאֵזוֹב וְהִזָּה עַל הָאָדָם הַטָּמֵא אוֹ עַל הַכֵּלִים וְהָיוּ הַמַּיִם שׁוֹתְתִין וְיוֹרְדִין מֵעַל הַטָּמֵא לָאָרֶץ. וְכֵן הַמַּיִם הַנִּתָּזִין בִּשְׁעַת הַזָּאָה עַל הָאָרֶץ אוֹ עַל הַטָּהוֹר הֲרֵי אוֹתָן הַמַּיִם טְהוֹרִים וְהַנּוֹגֵעַ בָּהֶן וְהַנּוֹשְׂאָן טָהוֹר. הִטְבִּיל אֶת הָאֵזוֹב לְהַזּוֹת עַל דָּבָר * שֶׁאֵינוֹ מְקַבֵּל טֻמְאָה הֲרֵי הַמַּיִם הַמְנַטְּפִין כְּשֵׁרִין לְהַזּוֹת מֵהֶן כְּמוֹ שֶׁבֵּאַרְנוּ. לְפִיכָךְ מְטַמְּאִין טֻמְאַת מֵי חַטָּאת לְפִי שֶׁלֹּא עָשׂוּ מִצְוָתָן שֶׁהֲרֵי הַטְּבִילָה הָיְתָה לְשֵׁם דָּבָר שֶׁאֵינוֹ מְקַבֵּל טֻמְאָה:‏

Comment: I understand about large groups but can the same be said for a long line, done individually?

Comment: Now looking at the Bartenura, it says "ha'ovrim" which leads me to think you could sprinkle a passing parade.

Comment: @rosends - correct. The first _assembly line_.